# Security certificate installation

Tags: security, ssl-certificate

I want to perform load test on some of the web services through VS2012. To do that we need to access the URL of the web service, but I am unable to do that since when i try to access the URL its displaying the below message

**Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 116.50.77.22 (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).
advanced
This server could not prove that it is 116.50.77.22; its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
Proceed to 116.50.77.22 (unsafe)**

How can i handle this, how can i install the security certificate or is there some other way i can access the given URL

Answer (score 8):

This error message appears to be from the Chrome browser when it detects an SSL certificate issue. I assume that the URL for the web service begins with `https://116.50.77.22` (secure HTTP).

Normally SSL certificates are issued to a computer host name or internet domain name versus an IP address. You may be seeing this message due to a name mismatch, and instead of using the IP address should use the name specified in the SSL certificate. You can view more details about what is causing the error by manually browsing to the web service URL, and if prompted with the original error choose to "Proceed to 116.50.77.22". You should then be able to click on the padlock icon in the address bar as shown below, and on the Connection tab you should see details similar to those shown. If you see "Server's certificate does not match the URL", click on the "Certificate information" link to view details on the SSL certificate being used by the server. The name you see after "Issued to:" is the name associated with the certificate and should be the name used in the URL. For example if you see "Issued to: M23458" you should use a URL beginning with `https://M23458/` to access the web service.

[image: Chrome HTTPS error screen shot]

If you see other errors listed under the Connection tab, my advice would be to search Stack Overflow for specific guidance in dealing with each one. You may need to resolve all before you original error message (your connection is not private...) will go away, and each one will require a different set of steps to address.